# Error on ubuntu fresh install

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to install ubuntu as the single os after using a dual boot of windows and Ubuntu. However after installing it goes to restart but when the computer comes back on it gives the error

> failure reading sector 0x4f4818 from hd0

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) which might help you out. Error messages like this might also be caused by hardware damage, but give boot-repair a try...

Comment: OK I will try that. How can this be a hardware damage I have installed Ubuntu before with no error?

Comment: As I said, it might be caused by a hardware damage, but not necessarly. I would give boot-repair a try, hope it works fine for you!